# Can Amazon Connect invoke a Lambda function alias

Tags: lambda, amazon-connect

I'm setting up a deployment pipeline for a lambda function that's we'd using in Amazon Connect. My intent was to create the alias PRODUCTION for the function, as well as TEST and UAT, and call that alias. However, after I create the PRODUCTION alias, I don't see it available in the Contact Flow page drop-down for available lambda functions. I have not found any posts that mention using lambda aliases with Connect, nor have I been successful at finding anything that says aliases cannot be used in Connect.

I've started looking for alternative deployment methods, but I would really like aliases because they appear simple to set up and use, and my deployment scripts for that are already done.

EDIT: I thought of checking if the Connect Service-linked role could be somehow expanded to call aliases, but that role cannot be altered in IAM.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

A coworker of mine suggested specifically giving the lambda alias access to Connect. All I had to do was run the lambda add-permission command, as explained [here](https://blogs.perficient.com/2018/11/30/invoking-lambda-functions-with-amazon-connect/) and then the arn of the alias in the Connect flow, and it worked.